# Celery: send_task method using chunks

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I'm using the send_task method to make remote calls, knowing that the tasks are not on the same server that I'm calling them from.

So I'm using:

```
celery.send_task(
        "example_name", args=[1,2,3], exchange=exchange, queue=exchange, ignore_result=True, connection=celery_conn
    )
```

I'm trying to use [Chunks](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chunks), but I can't find it anywhere how to use **chunks** with the **send_task** method.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Chunks can be used similarly. Celery serialises everything you send as input(`task, args, kwargs`) and sends them to the worker through the broker.

```
from celery import chunks
# it => iterable args
# n => number of items processed by a worker in a single task. Runs a for loop over the sequence internally
gr = chunks('example_name', it=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], n=1).apply_async()
```

For the written logic, if more than 3 workers are present, each chunk(ex.`[1,2,3]`) goes to each task as its `*args`.

Unfortunately, there is not much of documentation around chunks. For advanced use cases you should look at the source code and understand.